# failed to release a signed APK on Android Studio

Tags: android, apk, signing, android-studio-3.0

I am working on a project and when I try to release a signed APK from build.Gradle it gives me this error :

> Error:(20, 0) C:\Users\sephn\Downloads\Fingerprint2Sleep-master\signing.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
>   Open File

Here is my SigningConfigs:

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            def File signingConfFile = file("../signing.properties")
            def Properties signingConf = new Properties()
            signingConf.load(new FileInputStream(signingConfFile))

            storeFile file(signingConf['C:\\Users\\sephn\\Downloads\\APKs & JKSs\\FingerPrintQuickie.jks'])
            storePassword signingConf['MyPassword']
            keyAlias signingConf['MyKey']
            keyPassword signingConf['MyPassword']
        }
    }
```

Comment: `def File signingConfFile = file("../signing.properties")` .check location.

Comment: you better put your jks somewhere outside C drive.

Comment: could you specify more? what dou mean by check location ?

Comment: put your jks file in some otehr folder. the error maybe because your path have special characters. Try to put directly inside C and check

Comment: thank you ameer i'll try that

Comment: hava tried that yet the same problem remains. Gues it's something related with this part   

              def File signingConfFile = file("../signing.properties")
            def Properties signingConf = new Properties()
            signingConf.load(new FileInputStream(signingConfFile))

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all uses of `signingConfig` and `signingConfigs` in your `build.gradle` file. And instead, consider using Android Studio -> Build -> Generate Signed APK, and enter your credentials manually.

Sometimes gradle-based signing scripts do not always work. See also: [Android Studio 2.2 - Can no longer create unsigned release builds - "validateSigningReleaseLive FAILED"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767365/android-studio-2-2-can-no-longer-create-unsigned-release-builds-validatesig/39774266#39774266)

Comment: don't know how to remove all uses of signingConfig and sigingConfigs in my build.gradle since I am new to android studio.
I have tried to generate a signed APK using android studio and didn't work, all signature cases were greyed out.

Comment: @GreyIsh comment out or delete all lines and blocks that define `signingConfigs` and `signingConfig`

Comment: I did what you have said but it still gives this error: 

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
   Searched Location: 
  C:\Users\sephn\Downloads\Fingerprint2Sleep-master\app\src\debug\google-services.json
  C:\Users\sephn\Downloads\Fingerprint2Sleep-master\app\google-services.json

Comment: @GreyIsh Are you using Google Firebase or Analytics or AdMob in your app? You'll need to copy your `google-services.json` file into the `app` folder. Then ideally do a Gradle sync, then try to rebuild. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44318147

Comment: yes I am using all of that. 
Ok thank you I'll try that